# MySQL: Select on many-to-many relation table with set of conditions

Tags: mysql, select, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relation (MySQL) between labels and companies in an own relation table called `RELcomplabel`. It basically looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `RELcomplabel` (
    `IDcomplabel` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`IDcomplabel`),
    `Fcomp` INT NOT NULL ,
    `Flabel` INT NOT NULL
 );
```

Now I want to select all companies (all I want is `Fcomp`) having at least a given set of labels, e.g. `Flabel = 1 AND Flabel = 2 AND Flabel = 3`. If such a company is in the database, there are three rows in the table `RELcomplabel`, all having the same `Fcomp` but different `Flabel` (1, 2 and 3). The query should also - as good as possible - be dynamic in the number of labels, it should work for two but also for maybe ten given labels.

I found an ugly solution for two or three given labels, posted below. The problems with this solution are:

1. The ugliness to generate it dynamically.
2. The where-conditions on the inner joins have to check if `Ftype` of `t0` is different with `t1`, `t0` different with `t2` and `t1` different with `t2`.
3. That these queries generate all possible permutations of the set `(1,2,3)`, just to select one of it.

Solution for two labels:

```
SELECT s.fcomp FROM
(
    SELECT
        t0.fcomp,
        t0.ftype AS type0,
        t1.ftype AS type1
    FROM
        RELcomplabel AS t0
    INNER JOIN 
        RELcomplabel AS t1
        ON t0.fcomp = t1.fcomp
    WHERE
        t0.ftype <> t1.ftype
) AS s
WHERE
    s.type0 = 2
    AND s.type1 = 3;
```

Solution for three labels:

```
SELECT s.fcomp FROM
(
    SELECT
        t0.fcomp,
        t0.ftype AS type0,
        t1.ftype AS type1,
        t2.ftype AS type2
    FROM
        RELcomplabel AS t0
    INNER JOIN 
        RELcomplabel AS t1
        ON t0.fcomp = t1.fcomp
    INNER JOIN
        RELcomplabel AS t2
        ON t0.fcomp = t2.fcomp
    WHERE
        t0.ftype <> t1.ftype
        AND t0.ftype <> t2.ftype
        AND t1.ftype <> t2.ftype
) AS s
WHERE
    s.type0 = 1
    AND s.type1 = 2
    AND s.type2 = 3;
```

**For example**, using this testdata:

```
INSERT INTO `relcomplabel` (`IDcomplabel`,`Fcomp`,`Flabel`) VALUES (1,1,1);
INSERT INTO `relcomplabel` (`IDcomplabel`,`Fcomp`,`Flabel`) VALUES (2,1,2);
INSERT INTO `relcomplabel` (`IDcomplabel`,`Fcomp`,`Flabel`) VALUES (3,1,3);
INSERT INTO `relcomplabel` (`IDcomplabel`,`Fcomp`,`Flabel`) VALUES (4,2,2);
INSERT INTO `relcomplabel` (`IDcomplabel`,`Fcomp`,`Flabel`) VALUES (5,2,3);
```

I'm searching for a query that gives a result like

1. Searching for all companies with labels 1 & 2:

   ```
   -------
   |Fcomp|
   -------
   | 1   |
   | 2   |
   -------
   ```
2. Searching for all companies with labels 1, 2 & 3:

   ```
   -------
   |Fcomp|
   -------
   | 1   |
   -------
   ```

Thanks for reading this, and thanks for your help posting your approach to this problem!

Comment: Show some test data and the desired output. Also, I have the impression that your problem might be solved using the GROUP_CONCAT function - have a look at that.

Comment: `SELECT Fcomp,GROUP_CONCAT(Flabel)
FROM relcomplabel
GROUP BY Fcomp;`
gives me:
`(Fcomp, GROUP_CONCAT(Flabel) : (1, "1,2,3"; 2, "2,3")`.
Which is interesting, but I'm not quite there with it yet. Can you help me with a hint how to select only the companies having 1,2 or 1,2,3 in this result set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sqlfiddle to answer your question http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2711e/4

EDIT:
Added SQL in case the fiddle disappears:

```
SELECT Fcomp
FROM RELcomplabel
WHERE Flabel IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY Fcomp
HAVING COUNT(Flabel) >= 3
```

Comment: Someone suggested an edit and someone else rejected it, if as you stated you wanted at least that many matches change the = to >= . Made the change in the post as well, sorry, should have read the question a bit more carefully.

Comment: Also if a value of `Flabel` might appear twice for the same `Fcomp` use `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Flabel) >= 3` instead.